# Sklabel being covered by a sprite

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

I have a sklabel node and when I add a new sprite on to the same position the label gets covered by the sprite .

How can I make the label not get covered by anything that's added to the scene ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can solve the problem simply by changing the properties `zPosition`, so you can do:

```
labelNode.zPosition = 100;
```

Comment: @user3589173 - If this answer solved your issue, you should check it as correct.

Comment: who gave a negative vote without explaining why? also negative vote to the correct answer